# How to check for .NET 4 from InstallShield 2012?

Tags: installshield-2012

I'm usually in WIX-land instead of InstallShield.

What's the equivalent of `NETFRAMEWORK40FULL` in InstallShield?  Is there a better way to check for .NET 4.0 from InstallShield 2012?

Please note: I am not interested in installing it from the installer.  Just a simple test to inform the user they need to install .NET 4.0 before continuing.

EDIT:
I could use a bootstrapper, but would rather not if there's a native InstallShield way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much on InstallShield. I hope [this](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/documentLink.do?externalID=Q209084) may address you query.